# Custom Shape in Cocos3d

Tags: objective-c, cocos3d

I am developing an iPhone application that uses cocos3d. My question is: how to draw custom shape in cocos3d? for example a cylinder, a cylinder with an ellipse as its base instead of a circle, a polygone, etc. Can anyone please guide me how to start?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's good support for doing that in Cocos3D.

`CC3Mesh` has simple property settings for allocating space for vertex content, plus a large family of methods for getting and setting various vertex content. Make sure you understand how to use the `vertexContentTypes` property.

The source files `CC3ParametricMeshes.m` and `CC3ParametricMeshNodes.m` contain a number of examples of creating mesh shapes programmatically. Have a look at the implementations in those files.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I have read the files that you suggested and wrote a code to draw a cylinder, but I get weird shape. However, I am using an algorithm that generates the vertices and indices correctly (I already tested it in openGL). Can you help me find the problem if I posted my code?

Comment: I think i found the problem: it seems that the triangles have one transparent face, and one opaque face. But how is this happening? and how can we fix it?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a winding-order problem. Make sure you have consistent winding for your triangles. Counter-clockwise winding on all outward-facing triangles is the OpenGL default. However, if *all* the triangles in your mesh use clockwise winding, you can set the `shouldUseClockwiseFrontFaceWinding` property of your mesh node to YES, to use the opposite winding.

Comment: Thank you Bill! In my case, I have an algorithm that triangulates a polygon, so the triangles generated have random vertices order. I fixed the problem by setting the shouldCullBackFaces to NO.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out. While avoiding culling back faces will work, it means that you will be rendering twice as many faces as you need to, which will affect performance. It might not be a problem for small models, but if you encounter performance issues, consider revisiting the winding order of your mesh creation algorithm.

Comment: You are right, but for the moment, the performance is not an issue for me. I will get back to the creation algorithm once I finalize my app. Thanks a lot Bill!